# How to access secured API Management APIs linked to an Azure Static Web Application for local development with swa cli

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-static-web-app

How to call the secured API management linked APIs configured in azure portal when developing locally using SWA CLI? All I observed in the SWA configuration is meant for functions as APIs not the APIM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis-api-management

When adding API Management APIs to an azure static web app, an automatic proxy product is created on APIM securing access to the API for this app via /api prefix on the static web app domain. I did not see any mentions of how this works for local development to pass the user claims from SWA emulator to the API via that proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this recently and I don't think it's possible. My solution was to add a proxy to my dev server (in my case vite) to proxy all requests to the `/api` route to the Api Management URL, setting the necessary subscription key header.